# Adding a constant in "equal in distribution"

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Why is that adding a constant in this equation,

$x_B \overset {d}{=} (x_A+y)$

is equivalent to pushing some of the probability mass to the left

if $ y \le 0$.

Should it be pushing it down instead of left?

Am i wrong?

Link I read this from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these are random variables with distributions, then you will find that the cumulative distribution function of $X_b$ comes earlier than the  cumulative distribution function of $X_a$, i.e. $\Pr(X_b\le w) \ge \Pr(X_a \le w)$ for all $w$.  This might be interpreted as moving probability to the left, since if $\Pr(X_b\le v) = \Pr(X_a\le w)$ then $v \le w$.

If $X_a$ and $Y$ are independent and $Y$ does not take a single value, then you will also see that the distribution of $X_b$ is more spread out than that of $X_a$, which might be described as you do as "pushing down" the probabilities (since they sum or integrate to $1$)

Comment: I keep thinking it is equal. That is why I thought it is a linear addition. Forgot that it is equal in distribution.